# R command for summation over parametrized indices

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function in R so I command,

```
f <- function(d,r,k) {
    A <- d^(r-1)
    B <- **summation over i going from r to (k-1)**d^2i
    return (A+B)
}
```

I can not do the **.** part in the command above without help. So is there a command for summation where I can assign arbitrary parametric indices?

Comment: I edited your quasi code for readability.  Could you provide an example of what `d`, `r`, and `k` are as well as an example out put that you expect?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly (and d, r, and k are each scalars), what you want is something like:

```
f = function(d,r,k) {
  A = d^(r-1)
  B = sum(d^(2*(r:(k-1))))
  (A+B)
}
```

Essentially:

`r:(k-1)` expands into a list of the integers from `r` to `k-1`, so `d^(2*(r:(k-1))` is the list of `d^2i`. Call `sum()` on the list and you get the summation of the elements.

This could all be then condensed into:

```
f = function(d,r,k) {
  d^(r-1) + sum(d^(2*(r:(k-1))))
}
```

Comment: It should be `r:(k-1)` since `:` has higher precedence than the binary `-` operator.